# Wordpress Multiple one database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Can this solution be used for multiple WP installations on the same site?

For example, I have multiple blogs (multiple subdirectories), i.e. mysite.com/blog1, mysite.com/blog2, mysite.com/blog3, etc. on the same site. But, I want to combine the subdirectories to use one database (and theme, and plugins, etc.) Will this solution work? How can I read my all databases my all subdirectories from main website.

Comment: Have you thought about using wordpress's export/import facility and just moving all your content to the one site in your root? `Tools > Export/Import`

Comment: Hello Wezly, I have more sub-domains. I am trying to like pricegrabber.com or ebay.com They have sub-domains too. But they are managing all sub-domains from main website. I think I wrote this title is wrong. Actually I don't want one database. I want to try to connect my sub-domains databases from main website. Do you know how can I do that? :)

Answer (score 0):

When you say "one database" you mean "they should use the same set of data for themes and plugins, only posts are different" - right? Because otherwise you can of course use the same MySQL database and just use [different table prefixes in wp_config](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_Multiple_Blogs#Single_Database).

If you want to create something more integrated (f.e. users can log in on all sites) use WP Network (previously known as Wordpress MU).

As WP MU has been merged into core, this function is now refered to as [Creating a Network in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network), where you can globally install plugins and themes and then make them available for any subsites. In this case you wouldn't have to make several installations but install wordpress just once and then create several sub-sites.

(P.S. For future use, this question might be better suited for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Hello Christian,

I am really appreciate your help. I have already created WP Network and I have multiple WordPress website. I am trying to how can read all database from main website. For example:

I have "watches.website.com" sub-domain and I have here some products. I want to try to call that's products from "website.com" with search.

Can I do that like this?

But it's not only one sub-domain. I have more sub-domains. I am trying to like pricegrabber.com or ebay.com

They have sub-domains too. But they are managing all sub-domains from main website.

Thank you very much for your help again

Comment: As I haven't tried this myself yet, a bit of googeling brought up [solutions with plugins](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-search-across-wordpress-multisite-network) and [embedding Google Search instead](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/searching-across-network). Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Christian, Yes, that's it. That's correct one what am I looking for. But that plugins doesn't work on version 3.5.2. I will search more. Thank you so much.

Comment: Sure! But I can't do it right now. Because I opened new account. After 15 reputation I can do it.